# How to calculate the fundamental group of general configuration space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Define the configuration space of $n$ points in a general manifold $M$, where $\dim M=m$, as $K=(M^n-D)/S_n$ where $S_n$ is the permutation group and $D=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)| \exists i,j\ s.t. x_i=x_j \}$.

Then my question is

(1) How to prove $M=\mathbb{R}^m$ then $\pi_1(K)=S_n$ for $m>2$ and $\pi_1(K)=B_n$ for $m=2$ where $B_n$ is the Braid group. And what is the $\pi_1(K)$ when $m=1$?

(2) In general when $M$ is non-simply connected then what is $\pi_1(K)$ and how to calculate it? For example, $M=T^2$.

same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748136/how-to-calculate-the-fundamental-group-of-general-configuration-space

Comment: The first question is a basic fact about the braid groups. This is where their name comes from too.

Comment: These are called *braid groups of manifolds*. Key to calculations are the so-called *Fadell-Neuwirth fibrations*. You could probably find an answer for the torus by searching using these terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1a) Assume $n\geq 2$ since otherwise the quotient is trivial.  Since the action of $S_n$ is free, the quotient map is a covering map.  Since $m\geq 3$, and $M$ is simply-connected, $M^n-D$ is simply-connected by transversality since the codimension of $D$ is greater than or equal to 3 (so the inclusion map is 2-connected). From covering space theory, $\pi_1(K)=S_n$.

(1 b and c) See the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172717/braid-groups-and-the-fundamental-group-of-the-configuration-space-of-n-points)

(2) For non-simply connected $M$, use the idea in (1a) to get a quotient of $\pi_1(K)$ by the image of the fundamental group of $M^n-D$ via the covering map.  Use that to analyze $\pi_1(K)$.  See [*Configuration Spaces and Braid Groups* by Cohen & Pakianathan](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/jonpak/newbraid.pdf) for examples.

Note: Fred Cohen has written many papers about the topology of configuration spaces.  Here are some introductory notes I found by him hosted by NUS: [Lecture 1](https://imsarchives.nus.edu.sg/oldwww/Programs/braids/files/cohen1.pdf) and [Lecture 2](https://imsarchives.nus.edu.sg/oldwww/Programs/braids/files/cohen2.pdf).

Note:  By the Dold-Puppe Theorem, the fundamental group of the singular space $M^n/S_n$ is simply connected when $M$ is simply connected even though $(M^n-D)/S_n$ is not simply connected.

Comment: What's the Dold-Puppe Theorem?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Dold&s5=Puppe&s6&s7&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst&yearRangeSecond&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=150183%20%22result%22

Comment: Ah, cool.  This is sort of an unstable version of the Dold-Thom theorem.  For those who can't follow the above link, the paper is Ann. Inst. Fourier Grenoble 11 1961 201–312.

Comment: The link you provided has expired.

Comment: @maplemaple I did my best to fix it.  Thanks for pointing it out.